# How to resize the width of a column

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, jspinclude

I want to resize the width of a column that generated by  tag. Please help me to do that. My code goes like this...

```
<display:column property="Name" title="Name" />
<display:column property="Roll" title="Roll" />
<display:column property="class" title="class" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "resize"? Are you looking for overriding the column widths? Or you are really looking for resize capability on the table where a user can resize columns on their own?

Comment: Just to override the column width. sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `style` attribute of [`<display:column>`](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html)

```
<display:column property="Name" title="Name" style="width : 9%;" />
<display:column property="Roll" title="Roll" style="width : 55px;" />
<display:column property="class" title="class" style="width : 2cm;" /> 

<display:column property="prop" title="class" style="width : ......;" />
```